# Make a list of values that belong to each region

Tags: r, list, header, bioinformatics

I have a little trouble in R. I'm pretty new R users.

So I have a dataframe which looks like that (but much more longer) :

```
Chromosome  Start  End  Region_type  Region_id  NA
chr1 54159118 54159437 Peak MACS_peak_436 NA
chr1 54159120 54159439 Peak MACS_peak_436 NA
chr1 54159122 54159441 Peak MACS_peak_436 NA
chr1 54159124 54159443 Peak MACS_peak_436 NA
chr1 54159130 54159449 Peak MACS_peak_436 NA
chr1 54165713 54166032 Peak MACS_peak_422 NA
```

My first problem is that my file have no header, I upload my file with this command :

```
My_data=read.table("/home/toto/test.bed",sep="\t", dec=".",fill=TRUE,header = FALSE)
```

And after try to make a header like that

```
names(My_data)=c("chr", "start","end","Region_type","Region_id")
```

But when I want to take a column

```
My_column<-My_data$Region_type
```

It does not work. So I must to do like that :

```
My_column<-My_data[,4]
```

But I don't understand why the header doesn't work...

My second problem is that I'm trying to make a list of all the clones (clone is represented by chrX Start-End) that belong to each region (MACS_peak_xxx).

To do this I tried something like that :

```
region_list <- levels(My_data[,4])

region_list_clones <- lapply(region_list, function(x) which( My_data[,4] == x))
```

I'm pretty sure that's it's very easy to do...

Thank you for your help, I hope that's my example is clear :)

Comment: Your last column doesn't make sense, all `NA` and without a name?

Comment: make sure that the table is a data frame and not a matrix too

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What is the anticipated result and what are you seeing instead? (the column of `NA` values is probably because your text file has tab characters after the last column)

Comment: Thanks for your response.
The last column with all 'NA' is because I have a tab.. i don't know why I have this in my data but I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty unclear, but I *think* you're looking for `split(My_data, My_data[,5])`

*Update*

This will give you a list with a vector of regions for each region_id. It uses the `tidyr` and `purrr` packages from the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org)

```
My_data %>% unite(region, chr, start, end, sep=',') %>%
  split(.$Region_id) %>%
  map("region")
> $MACS_peak_422
> [1] "chr1,54165713,54166032"

> $MACS_peak_436
> [1] "chr1,54159118,54159437" "chr1,54159120,54159439" "chr1,54159122,54159441" "chr1,54159124,54159443" "chr1,54159130,54159449"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try to be more clear.
My first problem is that I can select one column because my file have not Header. So when I try to select one column with `My_column<-My_data$Region_type` it not work... I expect to have the data of my selected column here.

Comment: And my second problem is : I want to have in a variable all the coordinates which overlap with this ID  'MACS_peak_436'.
In my data I have lot of ID region and I want for each ID all the region that have this region ID

Comment: What is the output when you try `My_column<-My_data$Region_type`? Using your example data and your code assign column names, I get `"Peak", "Peak", "Peak", "Peak", "Peak", "Peak"`.

Comment: `region` and `variable` are not clearly defined in this context. Does `split(My_data, My_data[,5])` not give you what you're after? If not, please be more specific about what you are looking for.

Comment: I got an error, but I fixed it... My data were a list and not a dataframe... Thanks for  your help :)

Comment: Split didn't give me what I want
I want to create a list with all unique region ID (macs_Peak_n1, macs_Peak_n2,..., macs_Peak_n). 
For each region ID I want to make a list of all the clones (a clone is represented by chromosome, Start, End = the coordinates of the clones) that belong to each region.
So for example : 
macs_Peak_N1 : chr1,Start1,End1 , chr2, Start2, End2 
macs_Peak_N2 : chr7,start,end

Because the coordinates chr1 and 2 are annotated has ' macs_peaks_N1' and chr7 at macs_Peak_N2